# Greasemonkey: how can I autofill the login form?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, autofill

I want to auto fill my login form on (https://my.evon-home.com/login.html).

I am using Greasemonkey and I wrote a little Javascript.
But it is not working.

Here is my JS code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     user
// @namespace  https://my.evon-home.com/login.html
// @version  1
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==
document.getElementById("relayid").value = "123"
document.getElementById("user").value = "test";
document.getElementById("password").value = "test"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait for the page to load. Try this

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.getElementById("relayid").value = "999"
    document.getElementById("user").value = "demo";
    document.getElementById("password").value = "demo"
}, false);
```

If you want to submit the form then you can use the form's selector and then submit it.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.getElementById("relayid").value = "999"
    document.getElementById("user").value = "demo";
    document.getElementById("password").value = "demo"

    document.getElementsByClassName('form')[0].submit()
}, false);
```

Comment: what should i add if i want to submit also?

Comment: you want to click on login?

Comment: You can add a submit to your selector, like I have updated in the answer

Comment: I had one problem.I can not auto login with correct username and password .But when i manually fill my form and click login, i can successfully login.

Comment: All informations are auto filled,but just cannot succesfully auto login

Comment: Update your question or ask a new one, since the scope of your question has completely changed

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that adding the listener does not work properly on Violentmonkey with IceRaven (on Android). One could instead use the `@run-at` metablock (cf. https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40run-at) which seems to work cross-platform and cross-plugin:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name     user
// @namespace  https://my.evon-home.com/login.html
// @version  1
// @run-at   document-end
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==
document.getElementById("relayid").value = "123"
document.getElementById("user").value = "test";
document.getElementById("password").value = "test"
```